# How to create dynamic onclick elements in vuejs without repeating same value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a form in vuejs, where a group of inputs can be append onclick. It works fine, but the problem is, All inputs return the same value. I am sharing an image here :

[image]

I am sharing my code from template :

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in data.invoice_product" :key="k">
    <div class="row mb-2">
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <select class="form-control" v-model="data.invoice_product.product_id" 
               @change="getProductCost">
                  <option v-for="(product, i) in products" :key="i" :value="product.id">{{ 
                  product.product_name }}</option>
               </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" v- 
               model="data.invoice_product.quantity" @keyup="getProductCost">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" v- 
              model="data.invoice_product.total">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <span>
                   <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" @click="removeElement(k)" v-show="k || ( !k 
                   && data.invoice_product.length > 1)">Remove</i>
                   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" @click="addElement(k)" v-show="k == 
                   data.invoice_product.length-1">Add fields</i>
              </span>
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

from my script (I am excluding irrelevant code segments) :

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        data : {
            customer_id : '',
            vat : ''
        },
        inputs: [{
               product_id : '',
               quantity : '',
               total : ''
        }],
        input: {
               product_id : '',
               quantity : '',
               total : ''
         },
        products : []
    }
},

methods : {
   getProductCost() {
       axios.get('/api/product-cost? 
     product_id='+this.item.product_id+'&&quantity='+this.item.quantity, 
       this.data).then(response => {
           this.input.total = response.data
       })
    },
   addElement() {
       this.data.invoice_product.push({
            product_id : '',
            quantity : '',
            total : ''
       })
    },

    removeElement (index) {
       this.data.invoice_product.splice(index, 1)
    },
}
```

Input returns null if I use "input" instead :

[image]

Comment: because you get/set the same data from `data.invoice_product`. get/set the `input` instead.

Comment: input also has issue, if I use input, then it does not catch any data. I have updated my question, please check the image at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not providing correct data to v-model.

Here, you make an iteration, where you get "input" as an element.

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in data.invoice_product" :key="k">
```

But here, you are providing "data.invoice_product" instead of "input".

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="data.invoice_product.product_id" 
           @change="getProductCost">
```

Just change "data.invoice_product.product_id" to "input.product_id", and also do it for other inputs.

Comment: input also has issue, if I use input, then it does not catch any data. I have updated my question, please check the data(){} segment and the image at the bottom

Comment: @K..S.Azim, now, you are mixing "input" which is in data() and "input" which is element of iterable object.  Use v-for="(item,k) in data.invoice_product", and change relevant rows.

Comment: I am having another issue, I need these data in input (in data())

Answer (score 1):

You are already looping through `data.invoice_product` with this

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in data.invoice_product"> .... </div>
```

so the `v-model` on your `select` tag should be

```
<select v-model="input.product_id"> .... </select>
```

instead of

```
<select v-model="data.invoice_product.product_id"> .... </select>
```

Similar case for your `input` tags for `Quantity` and `Total`.

So, the code in your template should be something like this:

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in data.invoice_product" :key="k">
    <div class="row mb-2">
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <select class="form-control" v-model="input.product_id" 
               @change="getProductCost">
                  <option v-for="(product, i) in products" :key="i" :value="product.id">{{ 
                  product.product_name }}</option>
               </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" v- 
               model="input.quantity" @keyup="getProductCost">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" v- 
              model="input.total">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <span>
                   <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" @click="removeElement(k)" v-show="k || ( !k 
                   && data.invoice_product.length > 1)">Remove</i>
                   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" @click="addElement(k)" v-show="k == 
                   data.invoice_product.length-1">Add fields</i>
              </span>
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[Updated]

Your scripts should be left as it was before:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        data : {
            customer_id : '',
            vat : '',
            invoice_product: [{
               product_id : '',
               quantity : '',
               total : ''
            }],
        },
    
        input: {
               product_id : '',
               quantity : '',
               total : ''
         },
        products : []
    }
},

methods : {
   addElement() {
       this.data.invoice_product.push(this.input)
    },

    removeElement (index) {
       this.data.invoice_product.splice(index, 1)
    },
}
```

Comment: input also has issue, if I use input, it does not catch any data. I have updated my question, please check the data(){} segment and the image at the bottom

Comment: There was no need to change your script.

Comment: The issue still persists, I need these data (in input) to be passed in a post method

Comment: Are the input fields still showing the same value for all? As for the post method, we'd have to see what you're supposed to send to the API and how you are sending it.

Comment: Please check the question, I have updated the question including the method getProductCost(), it's a get method actually, sorry for the misinformation

Comment: and these data (input) will go as an array to APIs